# I can't import my own package on a test file

Tags: python

I built a Python package named `validateurgenerique` and published it on GitLab and pypi.

install from gitlab:

```
pip install validateurgenerique --index-url https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/54359493/packages/pypi/simple
```

install from pypi:

```
pip install validateurgenerique
```

But when I try to test it on my machine, I get this error (I used thony pypi search extension, it's there, I can find it, and it's installed)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Acer\Desktop\test_package\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from validateurgenerique import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'validateurgenerique'
```